# Slow docker push since Version 17.03.0-ce-mac2

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Before this version (before the number 17). 
"Layer already exists" push were very fast (near instant) on our custom registry.

Now since version 17 it takes near 1 second for each layer which already exists.
I've immediately seen the problem after the update. There were no other changes on the computer, Internet connection or the registry.

Is there something I can do to recover previous push speed?